# Error with getElementsByClassName() in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have html code:

```
<ul class="nav" id="topNav">
<li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 2 &nabla;</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">Menu 2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2.3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 5 &nabla;</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">Menu 5.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 5.2 &raquo;</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="icon">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
```

I want to get all elements with class = "dropdown" to add the onclick() attribute as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var y = [];
y = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
var att = document.createAttribute('onclick');
att.value = 'openChild(this)';
var i;
for (i=0; i < y.length; ++i){
  document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[i].setAttributeNode(att);
  var att1 = document.createAttribute('href');
  att1.value = 'javascript:void(0)';
  document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[i].setAttributeNode(att1);
}

}
</script>
```

However, only the first element can be executed:

```
<li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 2 &nabla;</a>
```

The following elements do not add the onclick().

Comment: You create only a single `onclick` attribute. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Don’t you see the error `InUseAttributeError: Attribute already in use`? Why would you use `setAttributeNode` with `onclick` instead of simply `.addEventListener("click", function(){ openChild(this); });`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't assign attribute strings to be parsed as JS from HTML - that's as bad as `eval`. Assign the handlers properly using Javascript instead.

You can use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` to iterate directly (over a `NodeList`), no need for `for` loops or selecting collections over and over again.

You also need to `preventDefault` the `event` to prevent the page from being replaced because the elements in question are `a`s:

```js
function openChild(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('opening ' + e.target.textContent);
}
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')
  .forEach(dropdown => dropdown.addEventListener('click', openChild));
```

```html
<ul class="nav" id="topNav">
<li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 2 &nabla;</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">Menu 2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2.3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 5 &nabla;</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">Menu 5.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="dropdown">Menu 5.2 &raquo;</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Note that `NodeList.forEach` is somewhat new - if you aren't using polyfills, then if you want to support ancient browsers, `call` the Array method instead:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown'),
  dropdown => dropdown.addEventListener('click', openChild)
);
```